# How to route controller class in .net core web api?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to build simple web api using .net core for doing basic calculations like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. I created controller class with multiple GET methods. controller class code as shown below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class OwnerController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public int Add(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 + value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Substract(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 - value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Multiply(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 * value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Divide(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 / value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "default";
        }

    }
}
```

How can I route this controller to do specific action when the respective API are called ?

Comment: Please describe the routes you would like to use for each action.

Comment: @KirkLarkin If i request for add,sub,mul and div operation by passing values from a client side then server api respond with respective get method

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are specified at controller level with your

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

This template only provides the route to the controller, expecting the framework to figure out the rest of the routing by the Http verbs/methods:

```
GET api/owner
POST api/owner
PUT api/owner
```

and so forth. Since you are reusing the GET method, you probably want to add the action name to your route. You can accomplish this in two ways:

1. Add the action name as part of your route template on the controller
2. Add the action name to the individual routes by specifying it with the verb

Example 1:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Example 2:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OwnerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Add")]
    public int Add(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
    [HttpGet("Subtract")]
    public int Substract(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 - value2;
    }
    ...
}
```

After either of these changes, you can make calls like

```
GET api/owner/add
GET api/owner/subtract
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following

```
    [HttpGet("addition")]
    public int Add(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
```

then the route for addition is GET api/owner/addition